# Errors on importing my oracle 10g database

Tags: oracle, import, oracle10g

I am running my oracle on a debian machine. Today I decided to create a new user and a new tablespace. Then I export a database with the user System which on the same machine. I got some error when I try to import to my new user account.
here is what I've done:

```
./imp mynewuser/passwrdb@orcl file=newdump_sept.dmp system/tomynewuser

Import: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Sep 29 18:06:23 2011

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release
10.2.0.1.0 - Production With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options

Export file created by EXPORT:V10.02.01 via conventional path

Warning: the objects were exported by SYSTEM, not by you

import done in US7ASCII character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set 
import server uses WE8ISO8859P1 character set (possible charset conversion) 
IMP-00085: multiple input files specified for unbounded export file 
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

Any suggestion to my problem?

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.error-code.org.uk/view.asp?e=ORACLE-IMP-00085 :

> Oracle Error :: IMP-00085
>
> multiple input files specified for unbounded export file Cause
>
> You specified multiple file names for the FILE parameter when doing an
>   import, but the header in the export file indicates that that the
>   export operation could create only one file. Specifying multiple file
>   names is valid for an import operation only if the export files were
>   created by an export operation in which the user specified a non-zero
>   value for the FILESIZE parameter. Action
>
> If you believe the export contains multiple files, verify that you
>   have specified the correct files. If you believe the export should be
>   in only one file then try the import operation again, but specify only
>   one value for the FILE parameter.

You should probably use:

```
./imp mynewuser/passwrdb@orcl file=newdump_sept.dmp fromuser=system touser=tomynewuser
```

For help: `imp help=y`

Comment: @Dwi Susanto: if it works you can accept the solution (click the check mark under the question score).

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved the error by importing the dump file by using SYS user instead of SYSTEM user and import working without errors.